# Photo archive / commentary software

Tags: gallery, metadata-editor, crowdsourcing, photography

I'm looking for a web server photo gallery package that has extensive tagging and retrieval capability.

I see the tag hierarachy as something like this:

- Program

  - Event class

    - Event

      - Sub event

        - Image

          - Story

            - Comment
- Year

  - Season
  - Month

    - Day
- Cohert

  - Class

    - Person

Some examples may make this clearer.

I'm working with a school archive.  The school had a very active outdoor program -- it's main selling feature.  So Program tags might be "Outdoor"  "Chores"  "Academic"  "School Life"

Under Outdoor, event classes might be "Hikes" "Christmas Dog Expedition" "Snowshoeing" "Canoe Trips"

Under Canoe trips might be Events  "1998 Methye, 1999 Churchill, 2000 Camsell, 2001 Sturgeon Weir 
(This is an over simplification there were several trips per year)

2000 Camsell might have sub events  "Wollaston & Hatchet Lakes", "Fond du Lac"  "Athatbasca" "Tazin River" "Taltson" "Great Slave"

Tazin River might have a sub-sub event "Dumping at Ogilthike"

A story can be connected to a tag at any level.  E.g. An alumnus may want to write a story about Canoeing in general.  Or about dumping at Ogilthike.  By inference something that is tagged at one level inherits the above tags.

There doesn't have to be an image connected with a story.  While images spark stories, the story can be attached to an event.  E.g:  an image of fishing may remind someone of a fishing story.  He attaches it to "1998 Methye" because he was pretty sure it was on that trip, and there are not existing tags for fishing underneath that image.

Commentary needs to be attached to a story.

---

I'd like to be able to delegate roles. E.g. Get one alumnus from each year to be the comment moderator for any stories tagged with that year.  Certain individuals are responsible for creating new tags at upper levels.

---

I'd like full roll back capability for the database to deal with vandalism.

---

Further requirements:

- Must run under Apache.
- Must use an opensource database engine.
- Code itself must be open source, because I know darn well that my wish list is a pipe dream, and I will ahve to write extensive chunks.

In addition to the event, time and people tags, I want a general keyword hierarchy.  E.g. dumping.  Anything tagged dumping is also behind the scene tagged canoeing and outdoor.  (Yes there can be other uses of "dumping"  those would be different places in the heirarchy.  E.g. Outdoor -> hygiene -> dumping,  and if you think teenagers don't have stories about this, you got another think coming.

Comment: "Code itself must be open source, because I know darn well that my wish list is a pipe dream, and I will ahve to write extensive chunk" - do you care much which language it is coded in, or are you willing to learn another, if need be?

Comment: try piwogo and galleryproject.org  Gets some plugins and/or write some of your own and it is a good solution.

Comment: I hadn't actually thought of coding it myself.  I prefer opensource because in principle all this meta data isn't hidden.  Nightmare:  10 years of commentary, and it's encased in some propriatary format.  *** I speak non modular perl (essentially perl 4) pascal, fortran (dating myself...) and a bit of bash.  Learning a new language is not impossible.  If I had to do it from scratch, probably a mix of Template Toolkit (for the web templates) postgres (for the back end) ImageMagick (for image resizing) and python (to hold it all together.)

Comment: Hadn't heard of piwogo.  I've heard of galleryproject, but had forgotten that it was extendibile.  Thanks.